# python izip which cycles through all iterables until the longest finishes

Tags: python, iterator

This turned out not to be a trivial task for me and I couldn't find any receipt so maybe you can point me to one or you have a ready, proper and well-tuned solution for that? Proper meaning works also for iterators that do not know own length (without `__len__`) and works for exhaustible iterators (e.g. chained iterators); well-tuned meaning fast.

Note: in place solution is not possible due to necessity to cache iterators outputs to re-iterate them ([Glenn Maynard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/136829/glenn-maynard) pointed that out).

Example usage:

```
>>> list(izip_cycle(range(2), range(5), range(3)))
[(0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1), (0, 2, 2), (1, 3, 0), (0, 4, 1)]
>>> from itertools import islice, cycle, chain
>>> list(islice(izip_cycle(cycle(range(1)), chain(range(1), range(2))), 6))
[(0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 1)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something inspired by `itertools.tee` and `itertools.cycle`. It works for any kind of iterable:

```
class izip_cycle(object):
    def __init__(self, *iterables ):
        self.remains = len(iterables)
        self.items = izip(*[self._gen(it) for it in iterables])

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.items

    def _gen(self, src):
        q = []
        for item in src:
            yield item
            q.append(item)

        # done with this src
        self.remains -=1
        # if there are any other sources then cycle this one
        # the last souce remaining stops here and thus stops the izip
        if self.remains:
            while True:
                for item in q:
                    yield item
```

Comment: Nice, one bug though: you probably want an additional `if self.remains` check before going to re-cycle iterator (otherwise you go one element too far in the finite case).

Comment: Just aesthetics: I actually thought about `if self.remains` after decreasing the counter in `_gen`. This way you can even skip this check in `__iter__` and have  `while True: yield next(self.items)`  (`izip` will stop for you). Few fast checks more in a bargain for not generating unnecessary tuple + 3 lines of code less + even better readability:) Nevertheless, I really like this one - does exactly what it should and is very readable.

Comment: @trybik: btw, it also shows that if any of the input sequences are infinite, then this will take infinite memory .. so that's probably not a good idea and you should limit yourself to sequences, which makes the whole problem much easier.

Comment: @THC4k: I know, but so does itertools.cycle too.

Comment: @trybik: Good point, I also added in what you suggested and it is much easier indeed :-)

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach which might work for you, depending on your requirement is:

```
import itertools

def izip_cycle(*colls):
    maxlen = max(len(c) if hasattr(c,'__len__') else 0 for c in colls)
    g = itertools.izip(*[itertools.cycle(c) for c in colls])

    for _ in range(maxlen):
        yield g.next()
```

The first thing this does it find the length of longest sequence so it knows how many times to repeat.  Sequences without `__len__` are counted as having 0 length; this might bewhat you want - if you have an unending sequence you probably want to repeat over the finite sequences.  Although this doesn't handle finite iterators with no length.

Never we use [`itertools.cycle`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to create a cycling version of each iterator and then use [`itertools.zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) to zip them together.

Finally we yield each entry from our zip until we've given our desired number of results.

If you want this to work for finite iterator with no `len` we need to do more of the work ourselves:

```
def izip_cycle(*colls):
    iters = [iter(c) for c in colls]
    count = len(colls)
    saved = [[] for i in range(count)]
    exhausted = [False] * count

    while True:
        r = []

        for i in range(count):
            if not exhausted[i]:
                try:
                    n = iters[i].next()
                    saved[i].append(n)
                    r.append(n)
                except StopIteration:
                    exhausted[i] = True
                    if all(exhausted):
                        return
                    saved[i] = itertools.cycle(saved[i])
            if exhausted[i]:
                r.append(saved[i].next())

        yield r
```

This is basically an extension of the [Python implementation of `itertools.cycle` in the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to run over multiple sequences.  We savd up items we've seen in `saved` to repeat and track which sequences have run out in `exhausted`.

As this version waits for all the sequences to run out, if you pass in something infinite the cycling will run on forever.

Comment: if you know `maxlen` why not to use `for` loop?

Comment: This breaks if the longest sequence doesn't have a length: `izip_cycle(iter([1,2,3,4]), [1,2]))`

Comment: @SilentGhost - a for loop is probably nicer. Have changed the code.

Comment: @mike: if it doesn't have a length it's not a sequence.

Comment: @SilentGhost, I stand corrected, but change my comment to "iterable" and it is code still breaks.

Comment: Iterators don't have `__len__`; its behavior isn't even clearly defined for iterators.

Comment: On the other hand, the OP's question leaves something unspecified: how is it cycling?  Iterators can't be rewound, so either 1: he really means sequences, or 2: you need to cache the entire output of the iterator to cycle it.  #1 seems more likely.

Comment: Have added an alternate version which works for iterators but isn't as pretty.

Comment: @Dave: alternative ver works well; meanwhile I came up with smth v. similar but higher-level (w/o explicit yield and caching)
@Glenn: good comment and I meant #2, i.e. caching

Answer (score 0):

```
def izip_cycle_inplace(*iterables):
    def wrap(it):
        empty = True
        for x in it: empty = yield x
        if empty: return
        next(counter)
        while True:
            empty = True
            for x in it: empty = yield x
            if empty: raise ValueError('cannot cycle iterator in-place')
    iterators = [wrap(i) for i in iterables]
    counter = iter(iterators)
    next(counter)
    while True:
        yield [next(i) for i in iterators]

def izip_cycle(*iterables):
    def wrap(it):
        elements = []
        for x in it:
            yield x
            elements.append(x)
        if not elements: return
        next(counter)
        while True:
            for x in elements: yield x
    iterators = [wrap(i) for i in iterables]
    counter = iter(iterators)
    next(counter)
    while True:
        yield [next(i) for i in iterators]
```

Comment: These are slick, but fall into infinite loop with exhaustible iterator. Try, e.g. `list(itertools.islice(izip_cycle(itertools.cycle(range(1)), itertools.chain(range(1), range(1))), 3))`

Comment: Well, you asked for an in-place solution. ;) Although these also get stuck with empty iterables. If either of the for loops complete without yielding anything you'd really want to raise a ValueError, but I can't see an elegant way to add that...

Comment: Ok, fixed all the issues now, I think.